# I'm using a form to store input in a variable, then display that variable onscreen. No inner script allowed

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables, input

So here is my code, we are not allowed to use inner javaScript on the html code at all. He doesn't want us to use document.getElementsByID, and he doesn't want us to use document.write. Every time i enter input, my new message in my h3 tag shows up onscreen for a split second, then reverts back to the default h3 message. I've scoured the web for hours and everything seems to require scripting in the html code. is this even possible? the console log of the new message shows up fine, it just will not stay on the page no matter what i try. This is only step 1 of this weeks lab.

**HTML**

```
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-    width, initial-scale=1,user-scalable=yes">
<title>BrightIdeas</title>
<link rel="reset" href="css/reset.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">


    <div class="header">
        <div class="header_left">
            <h1>BrightIdeas</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="header_right">

                <a href "#" onclick="logIn()">Login</a> | <a href="signUp.html">Sign Up!</a> | <a href="faq.html">FAQ</a> | <a href="#">Support</a>
        </div>
    </div>



<div class="content-left">


        <div class="content-left-top">
        <h3>Bright Ideas will change your life!</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minimum veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi us aliquip ex a commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugait nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim est laborum.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="content-left-bottom">

        <ul><strong>Here's why you need Bright Ideas</strong>
        <li>It fits your lifestyle</li>
            <li>It's awesome</li>
            <li>We say so</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>



    <div class="content-right">
        <img id="blinking_image" src="images/brightIdea1.png" alt="an image of a lightbulb">
    </div>
</content>


    <div class="footer">

        <div class="footer_left">
            <ul><strong>Contact Us</strong>
                    <li>BrightIdeas</li>
                    <li>666 Sixth Street</li>
                    <li>Amherst, NY 12345</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="footer_right">
                    <ul><strong>Sitemap</strong>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                    </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

 </div>
 <script src="js/app.js"> </script>
 <script> document.write(h3).innerHTML=newh3</script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function logIn() {
  var userName = prompt("Please enter your username ");
  var newh3 = document.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0].innerHTML;
  var personalizedMsg = newh3;

  newh3 = userName + ", " + personalizedMsg;

  console.log(newh3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is you already have an internal script:

```
<script> document.write(h3).innerHTML=newh3</script>
```

This is the problem you are having. Remove this, and your code will work perfectly!